# Java 8 Lambda - Intersection of Two Lists

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, intersection

I am trying to find `intersection` of two lists based on some condition and doing some steps. Couldn't find a way to do it (in learning stage) :)

```
Double totalAmount = 0.00d;
Double discount = 0.00d;


List<OrderLineEntry> orderLineEntryList = orderEntry.getOrderReleases().stream()
    .flatMap(orderReleaseEntry -> orderReleaseEntry.getOrderLines().stream())
    .filter(orderLineEntry -> orderLineEntry.getStatus().equals("PP") || orderLineEntry.getStatus().equals("PD"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

for (OrderLineEntry orderLineEntry : orderLineEntryList) {
    for (SplitLineEntry splitLineEntry : splitReleaseEntry.getLineEntries()) {
        if (splitLineEntry.getOrderLineId().equals(orderLineEntry.getId()) && splitLineEntry.getStatusCode() != "PX") {
            totalAmount += orderLineEntry.getFinalAmount();
            couponDiscount += orderLineEntry.getCouponDiscount() == null ? 0.00d : orderLineEntry.getCouponDiscount();
        }
    }
}
```

As you see, the logic is simple

Get All items from order based on some filter `list` and intersect with another `list` and do some stuff.

Comment: The most efficient way to find an intersection is to use a Set or a Map. I suggest you build a set by collecting an appropriate groupingBy.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, Can you help me achieve the same with Lambda. I am creating list just to find intersection. Typical Java coding, I would use `Map` :)

Answer (score 143, accepted):

The simplest approach is this:

```
List<T> intersect = list1.stream()
                         .filter(list2::contains)
                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I have seen this example. How do i use this for my use case. Since `list1` and list2 are of different types and I need to compare them on assume `list1.id == list2.fk_id`

Comment: As an optimisation I would turn list2 into a HashSet first.

Comment: contains is O(n), so this is a O(n^2) set intersection operation

Comment: I have tried this, but I think ::contains use == instead of equals, the result intersection may be empty.

Comment: We need to implement HashCode & equals for T, in order to intersect works fine.

Comment: I would rather use Set<T> as the outcome to eliminate duplicates. You could also add `.filter(Objects::nonNull)` to avoid null values if you want.

Answer (score 14):

> I need to compare them on assume list1.id == list2.fk_id

First build up a set of the fk_id;

```
Set<Integer> orderLineEntrSet = orderEntry.getOrderReleases().stream()
    .flatMap(orderReleaseEntry ->
orderReleaseEntry.getOrderLines().stream())
    .filter(orderLineEntry -> { 
            String s = orderLineEntry.getStatus(); 
            return "PP".equals(s) || "PD".equals(s); 
    })
    .map(e -> e.getId())
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());

double[] totalAmount = { 0.0 };
double[] couponDiscount = { 0.0 };
orderLineEntryList.stream()
    .flatMap(sre -> sre.getLineEntries().stream())
    .filter(ole -> orderLineEntrySet.contains(ole.getOrderLineId())
    .filter(ole -> !"PX".equals(ole.getStatusCode()))
    .forEach(ole -> {
            totalAmount[0] += ole.getFinalAmount();
            if (ole.getCouponDiscount() != null)
                couponDiscount[0] += ole.getCouponDiscount();
        });
```

You can avoid using a reference to an array object by using reduce function. e.g. see how Collectors.averagingDouble is implemented. But I find this more complicated.

Note: this is O(N) by using a set of ids rather than using a list of matching ids which would be O(N^2)

Comment: Not sure about the O(N). Since you need to do a 'contains' on the second list, I'd think this is still O(N^2).

Comment: @HakunaM Set.contains using a hash set is O(1) amortized (and O(log N) for a tree set) Collectors.toSet() returns a hash set.

Answer (score -8):

`List<T> intersect = list1.stream().filter(set1::contains).collect(Collectors.toList());`

This will work as long as `T` is a `String`, `Integer`, `Float`, etc. where the equals and HashCode methods are straightforward. But if the `T` is a custom object, we need to implement HashCode & equals

Comment: this answer, added a year later, is no different than top voted answer other than being more wordy and less formatted..