# intersection and union in java (bit strings)

Tags: java, set

What is the operation used in java to represent Intersection and Union?

For example,
{a,c} = 101
{c,b} = 011 and the interaction result should be 001. 
If I want to represent this in java 101 ∩ 011
what is the operation that should be used in correspond to ∩ and ∪ ?

Comment: Assuming you're using Java 8, see the answer here from Silas Reinagel: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31683375/java-8-lambda-intersection-of-two-lists

Comment: `addAll` and `retainAll`.

Answer (score 2):

See the section `set interface bulk operations` in [the official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html). You want `addAll` and `retainAll`.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to the [Set Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html).

According to the above website:

> s1.addAll(s2) — transforms s1 into the union of s1 and s2. (The union
>   of two sets is the set containing all of the elements contained in
>   either set.)
>   s1.retainAll(s2) — transforms s1 into the intersection of
>   s1 and s2. (The intersection of two sets is the set containing only
>   the elements common to both sets.)

Here is an example:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
public class Intersection
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Set<String> s1 = new HashSet<String>();
      Set<String> s2 = new HashSet<String>();

      s1.add("a");
      s1.add("c");

      s2.add("b");
      s2.add("c");

      s1.retainAll(s2);

      System.out.println(s1);
   }
}
```

The output of the above is:

> [c]