# Manipulation list and removed data from list

Tags: java

```
List<Object1> list1 = userVo.getMstCardTypeVOs();
Object1 object1 = new Object1();
object1.setId(1);
object1.setName("Test");
-- More fields which are not matched with object2
list1.add(object1);

object1 = new Object1();
object1.setId(2);
object1.setName("Test1");
 -- More fields which are not matched with object1
list1.add(object1)

List<Object2> list2 = mapMenuProgramRepo.findAll();
Object2 object2 = new Object2();
object2.setId(1);
object2.setName("Test");
list1.add(object2);

object2 = new Object2();
object2.setId(2);
object2.setName("Test1");
list1.add(object2);
```

What I need to check same id exist in list1 with reference from list2?

I have used below code:

```
for (Object1 object1 : obj1) {
    for (Object2 obj2: obj2) {
        if (object2.getId().equals(object1.getId())) {
            // removed entry from the list1
            // We can removed by using iterator instead of list
        }
    }
}
```

What are the better way and optimized way using jdk8 or 7?

Comment: My Opinion You use JDK 8 it is more effective to JDK7

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31683375/java-8-lambda-intersection-of-two-lists) might be worth looking at

Answer (score 0):

> // removed entry from the list1

If you need to remove from one of lists than you can use following code

```
list1.removeIf(val1 -> list2.stream()
.filter(val2 -> val2.getId().equals(val1.getId()).findFirst().orElse(null) != null)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with JDK8 streams as shown below by using `noneMatch()` method:

```
list1.removeIf(value1 -> 
   list2.stream().anyMatch(value2 -> 
   (value2.getId().equals(value1.getId))));//equal ids then remove it from list1
```

If you have to solve the problem without using streams, then you need to use **[Iterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html)** (look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/collection.html) for example on remove) and then loop through the `list1` and `list2` and `remove` the matched elements from `list1`

---

Also, I suggest never create any class names (even example classes) with `Object1` or `Object2`, etc.. as it is very confusing for other developers(i.e., it is not easy to understand the code with class names as `Object1`, `Object2`).

Comment: I am confused: it seems to me that it should be `anyMatch` instead of `noneMatch`

Comment: If need to change the condition for equals to if not not matched the removed then what would be the changes in the above logic?

Comment: like this: `!(value2.getId().equals(value1.getId))`

Comment: With .noneMatch its not working , with .allMatch() its working. thanx

Comment: yes, it should be `allMatch`, anyhow great that it works now, you can accept my answer if it helps

Comment: From OP's question, what he is looking for is: Remove the entry from `list1`, if there is an entry `list2` with same ID.  Neither of `noneMatch` and `allMatch` works.  It should be `anyMatch`.

Answer (score 0):

Although using stream like other answers looks cool, imho it may not be optimal, especially when there is a lot of values in `list2`.

Instead of using stream to verify if a value exists in `list2`, which gives complexity of `O(M*N)` (M,N for number of values in `list1` and `list2`), I would recommend doing things like:

```
Set<> excludeIds = list2.stream().map(Object2::getId).collect(Collectors.toSet());
list1.removeIf(v -> excludeIds.contains(v.getId()));
```

Easier to understand, and run faster.

With a `HashSet`, the complexity of the logic reduce to `O(M+N)`