# Java Stream : Create new List from 2 Lists keeping only matching values

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I'm working with java streams and I have an issue.
I have a List like:

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

and another like:

```
[1,3,5,7,9]
```

My question is how can I create a new list like:

```
[1,3,5]
```

Thanks.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#retainAll-java.util.Collection-, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-

Comment: `list1.stream().filter(i -> list2.contains(i)).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: As @YCF_L has shown, but if the lists get large, I’d use `list1.stream().filter(new HashSet<>(list2)::contains).collect(Collectors.toList());` instead, to avoid *n×m* time complexity.

Comment: do you have any performance restrictions in terms of memory or runtime complexity? can streams be assumed to be sorted?

Comment: This is a really nice trick @Holger

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31683375/java-8-lambda-intersection-of-two-lists

Answer (score 4):

There is a much simpler way than using a stream here:

```
List<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<>(list1);
newList.retainAll(list2);
```

However, as pointed out by @Holger, if the lists are large, this solution can be inefficient, so instead try:

```
newList.retainAll(new HashSet<>(list2));
```

You have a stream answer in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

You can also utilize the [`retainAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#retainAll(java.util.Collection)) method to achieve this.

```
 ArrayList<Integer> newArr = new ArrayList<>(arr);   //Create a new List based off the first list
 newArr.retainAll(arr2);   //Retain only the elements in the first list and second list
```

In this example `newArr` would be `[1,3,5]`

Answer (score 1):

If you have lists

```
List l1 = ..., List l2 = ...
```

You can do:

```
List result = l1.stream().filter(x -> l2.contains(x)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```